# Rails, remove quotes from around active record value in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a query that is failing because the scope is running a query like this :`'%'email'%'`
The internal quotes are causing the problem, how can I get rid of them?

```
user.rb (User Model)
#it's checking a text field to see if it contains the email address
@locations = Location.has_permission(self.email)

location.rb (Location Model)
scope :has_permission, lambda { |email| where("locations.permissions LIKE '%?%'",email)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope should be building the pattern using string concatenation:

```
scope :has_permission, lambda { |email| where("locations.permissions LIKE '%' || ? || '%'",email)}
```

`||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL so the following:

```
'%' || ? || '%'
```

In Ruby, ends up the same as:

```
'%' + email + '%'
```

This is a question of style, wrapping the email address in percents in Ruby (either with `+` or interpolation) yields the same result in the end. Perhaps I'm just more comfortable with SQL than a lot of Rails people.

Comment: It seems to work. Have a question. What does the || do? Why do you have the second set of internal quotes?

Comment: @John: `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL so `'%' || ? || '%'` ends up the same as `'%' + email + '%'` in Ruby.

Comment: Is there an advantage to this over using interpolation, or is it safer?

Comment: @Dave: Just a question of style, wrapping the email address in percents in Ruby (either with `+` or interpolation) yield the same result in the end. Perhaps I'm just more comfortable with SQL than a lot of Rails people.

Comment: Ah, okay, wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something dumb, although it seemed equivalent. I'm fine w/ SQL, just find the Rubier version much easier to read :)

Comment: Remember to enclose the concatenated string: `LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')` otherwise SQL will evaluate `LIKE '%'` first and return all your records. Either that or use `LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`

Comment: @MikeCampbell: What database puts the precedence of `LIKE` before `||`? That's a bit bizarre and I've never seen it. Is it some database that doesn't understand the standard SQL string concatenation operator?

Comment: in my test on MySQL: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%' || 'Mike' || '%'` is returning me every record from that table.

Comment: @MikeCampbell: Does MySQL understand that `||` is string concatenation? Or do you have to turn on some obscure "pay attention to the SQL standard" flag? I think `concat` is a MySQLism that other databases may or may not understand. Sorry, I don't use MySQL that much, I got tired of its shenanigans.

Comment: Ah, turns out that MySQL `||` means OR so it won't work at all in MySQL. `CONCAT` is actually very widely supported, I'd go so far as to say, more so than `||`.

Answer (score 2):

```
scope :has_permission, 
      lambda { |email| where("locations.permissions LIKE ?", "%#{email}%") }
```

There's a way to do this with AREL, too, with a `matches("%#{email}%")` but I'm not sure of the syntax to get to the nested permissions.